# Angular material mat-table sticky header row error when i filter for column

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-table

I have an angular Material table with three fixed columns ("Type, Cod, Station") and when I start filtering the data by columns the table behaves in a wrong way, leaving a blank space between columns.

What I want is that when filtering by some column I don't get that blank space.

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCBch.png)

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSourceH" matSort matTableExporter #exporter="matTableExporter" #sortH="matSort" class="tr_table">

                    <ng-container *ngFor="let disCol of displayedColumnsH; let colIndex = index"
                        matColumnDef="{{disCol}}" [sticky]="isIn(disCol)">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
                            <div [innerHTML]="displayedColumnsNamesH[colIndex]"></div>
                        </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"  [style.background-color]="element[disCol+'Color']" [style.color]="element[disCol+'Texto']">
                            <div *ngIf="element[disCol]" [innerHTML]="element[disCol]"></div>
                            <div *ngIf="!element[disCol] && !isIn(disCol)" [innerHTML]="'-'"></div>
                        </td>
                    </ng-container>

                    <ng-container *ngFor="let filCol of displayedFilterColumnH; let colIndexF = index"
                        matColumnDef="{{filCol}}" [sticky]="colIndexF<3">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [style.text-align]="center" [attr.colspan]="1">
                            <mat-form-field class="columnas" floatLabel='never'>
                                <input matInput placeholder="Filtro" type="text"
                                    [(ngModel)]='filterTableH[displayedColumnsH[colIndexF]]'
                                    name="displayedColumnsH[colIndexF]"
                                    (keyup)="hanlerOnChangeFilter($event, 'H',displayedColumnsH[colIndexF])">
                                <button mat-button *ngIf="filterTableH[displayedColumnsH[colIndexF]]"
                                    (click)="handlerClearFilterField('H',displayedColumnsH[colIndexF])" matSuffix
                                    mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear">
                                    <mat-icon class="material-icons-outlined">close</mat-icon>
                                </button>
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </th>
                    </ng-container>

                    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsH; sticky: true"></tr>
                    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedFilterColumnH"></tr>
                    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsH;"></tr>
                </table>
```